# How to save multiple documents in one command in Mongodb / Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would have thought this was straightforward but I think it might give unexpected results.  I basically load a few documents into a variable.. then I want to save the whole document back to MongoDB.

Do I have to save each one individually using save
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/

Or can I send them as an array using updatemany https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

it doesn't seem that clear in the docs how to do that.. if you can.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is unclear from the documents? What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are examples to add new documents in bulk , but not update multiple .

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Native MongoDB Driver for NodeJs, you can use insertMany if you want to create new documents, I think it will work if you have an array of object (be careful to well name fields) like :

```
var your_variable = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 2, b: 3, c: 1, d: 4}];


db.YourCollection.insertMany(your_variable, function(err, result) {
    // Your treatement
});
```

If you want to update multiple with multiple value, it's impossible (or after many research I didn't find a good solution), you have to make multiple request.

Comment: Ok, yes I wanted to update multiple not add  .thank you .

Comment: After, if you want to update multiple documents with the same values, you can using updateMany

Comment: how? Can you give an example? Have you tested for sure?

Answer (score 1):

To update multiple documents with the same values, you can query like this :

```
db.YourCollection({/* filter empty to update all document */}, {
    $set: {
        field1: new_value1,
        field2: new_value2
        // etc...
    }
}, function(err, result) {
    // your treatment
});
```

If you want to update multiple documents but not all, use the method like this :

```
db.YourCollection({fieldToFilter: value}, {
    $set: {
        field1: new_value1,
        field2: new_value2,
        // etc...
    }
}, function(err) {
    // Your treatment
});
```

the `$set` stage is for change the value of the fields, but you can use any operator from : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/

You're not forced to use callback function, you can use Promise too

Comment: Thanks.. but not really what I am looking for @Nicolas .  I was wanting to load docs , make some changes to them and then save the whole doc ( in bulk ) .  I will do them individually.